# Build list of substrings created by separating a string by a match

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
"a_b_c_d_e"
```

I would like to build a list of substrings that result from removing everything after a single `"_"` from the string. The resulting list would look like:

```
['a_b_c_d', 'a_b_c', 'a_b', 'a']
```

What is the most rubyish way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s = "a_b_c_d_e"
a = []
s.scan("_"){a << $`}                                                            #`
a # => ["a", "a_b", "a_b_c", "a_b_c_d"]
```

Comment: clever use of comment to fix syntax highlight problem.

Comment: Also a clever answer, though not sure it's most Rubyish. Seems kinda Perlish to me :) Regardless, upvoted.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you. Regarding your first comment, that is a technique I have used over the years of using emacs. Regarding your second comment, I actually felt the same thing. If I replace ``a << $` `` with `a.push($PREMATCH)`, it might be slightly more Rubyish. It would be better if it were possible to create an iterator out of `scan`.

Comment: What does the `$\`` signify?

Comment: The best answer here.

Comment: Educational, as always.

Comment: @Dickie, see "Special global variables" at [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html): "`$\`` contains string before match".  Changing the block to `{puts $\`; a << $\`}` causes the following to be printed: `"a"`, `"a_b"`, `"a_b_c"`, 
`"a_b_c_d"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can `split` the string on the underscore character into an `Array`. Then discard the last element of the array and collect the remaining elements in another array joined by underscores. Like this:

```
str = "a_b_c_d_e"
str_ary = str.split("_") # will yield ["a","b","c","d","e"]
str_ary.pop # throw out the last element in str_ary
result_ary = [] # an empty array where you will collect your results
until str_ary.empty?
  result_ary << str_ary.join("_") #collect the remaining elements of str_ary joined by underscores
  str_ary.pop
end

# result_ary = ["a_b_c_d","a_b_c","a_b","a"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: EDITED: need to pop one element before entering the loop and then pop again as the last instruction in the loop. Previous solution pushed an empty string into `result_ary`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about “most rubyish”, my solutions would be:

```
str = 'a_b_c_d_e'

(items = str.split('_')).map.with_index do |_, i| 
  items.take(i + 1).join('_')
end.reverse
########################################################
(items = str.split('_')).size.downto(1).map do |e|
  items.take(e).join('_')
end
########################################################
str.split('_').inject([]) do |memo, l| 
  memo << [memo.last, l].compact.join('_') 
end.reverse
########################################################
([items]*items.size).map.with_index(&:take).map do |e| 
  e.join('_')
end.reject(&:empty?).reverse
```

My fave:

```
([str]*str.count('_')).map.with_index do |s, i| 
  s[/\A([^_]+_){#{i + 1}}/][0...-1]
end.reverse
```

Comment: I like your last approach. However, I don't quite understand everything about the regex you've used. Can you please explain it better?

Comment: `i+1` times match `blah_`. Results in `blah_blah_blah_`. I don’t like `chop` function on string, that’s why I take everything but last symbol manually then.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby ships with a module for [abbreviation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html).

```
require "abbrev"

puts ["a_b_c_d_e".tr("_","")].abbrev.keys[1..-1].map{|a| a.chars*"_"}
# => ["a_b_c_d", "a_b_c", "a_b", "a"]
```

It works on an Array with words - just one in this case. Most work is removing and re-placing the underscores.